# If $E$ is Borel, then $\lambda(E)=\sum_{k \in Z} \lambda((E-k) \cap[0,1))$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that the measure for a Borel set $E$ can be as

$$\lambda(E)=\sum_{k \in Z} \lambda((E-k) \cap[0,1))$$

Where $A-k$ is just a translated set. But I'm having trouble with this. At first I thought this was something similar with the idea of the proof of the following statement $\frac{\lambda(E \cap I)}{\lambda(I)}>1-\epsilon$, but it did not take me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$(E-k)\cap[0,1)=(E-k)\cap([k,k+1)-k)=(E\cap[k,k+1))-k,$$so $$\lambda(E-k\cap[0,1))=\lambda(E\cap[k,k+1)).$$

Comment: And since every Borel set can be written as the union of the latter sets u mention, i got the result. thats right?

Comment: @AlekMurt Use $\sigma$-additivity and disjointness (and translational invariance). It does not matter that $E$ is Borel, just that it is measurable